Application of Banach fixed point theorem to integral equation $\int_0^1 \sin(x) f(x) dx=0$.
Suppose we want to solve the integral equation $$\int_0^1 \sin(x) f(x) dx=0\cdots (1)$$ on the space of continuous functions $C[0,1]$. I am wondering if it is possible to apply the Banach fixed point theorem in the following way?
We may write above equation as:
$$
f(x)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sin(x) f(x)dx \cdots (2).
$$
Now, define a an integral operator $T$ on $C[0,1]$ as,
$$T(f(x))=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sin(x) f(x) dx$$
Let $||.||$ denote the sup norm on $C[0,1]$, then with usual computations, we can show for continous maps $f$ and $g$ that,
$$||Tf-Tg||\leq \frac{1}{2}||f-g||.$$
Hence, by Banach contraction, the equation $(2)$, and hence equation $(1)$ has a unique solution, which should be $f(x)=0$.
Is this argument correct?
I did Picard iteration for initial $f_0(x)=1$, but the sequence of iterations diverge. The first few iterations are:
$$ f_0(x) = 1 ,
 f_1(x) \approx 1.22985 ,
 f_2(x) \approx 1.5126 ,
f_3(x) \approx 1.8606 ,
f_4(x) \approx 2.2875 ,
f_5(x) \approx 2.8116.$$
So I think something is wrong with the application of Bnacah fixed point.

$||Tf-Tg||\leq \frac{1}{2}||f-g||$ seems to be false.

The inequality fails for $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=0$.

It is false. I found the mistake, thanks.

In general the operator of the form $T=I+S, $ on at least two dimensional space, where $S$ is a one dimensional operator, is not a contraction. The existence of solution of $(1)$ can be derived from $F(t)=\int_0^1 \sin x, (x-t),dt.$Then $F(t)<0$ for $t>1$ and $F(t()>0$ for $t<0.$ Hence $F(t)$ vanishes for some $t.$

Notice that in your Picard iteration, you are only working with constant functions, you are not performing the fixed point iteration on $C[0,1]$, but on $\mathbb{R}$, in which case the map is given by
$$
T:c\mapsto c + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sin(x)c~\mathrm{d}x = \left(1 + \sin^2(1/2)\right)c, 
$$
so $|Tc|>|c|$ and the map is not a contraction over $\mathbb{R}$. As the commenters pointed out, this is not a contraction over $C[0,1]$ either.
Furthermore, even if you were considering this as an equation over $C[0,1]$, then the solution is highly nonunique. For example, you can take any function $f(x)$ and then $g(x) = f(x) - \int_0^1 f(x)\sin(x)~\mathrm{d}x$ is a new function satisfying your equation. Since the fixed-point theorem admits a unique fixed point, I doubt it can be used on this problem without massive restrictions.
